Are faith & wisdom two wings of a bird in Buddhism?
I read the following ideas on the internet but could not find an authoritative source for these ideas:

how one gains faith after loosing faith (with wisdom, conviction) and
balances wisdom and faith. This is in fact a very important aspect of
many of the Buddhas, as well as sects of Buddhism teachings. Gelugpa
teachings of lojong explain about the importance of balancing faith
and wisdom "like 2 wings of a bird", as well as faith of importance in
theravada school (until one reaches state of stream entry)
Gelugpa teachings of lojong explain about the importance of balancing
faith and wisdom "like 2 wings of a bird", as well as faith of
importance in theravada school (until one reaches state of stream
entry)

All I could find on the internet was:

Just as the birds fly through God's creation on two graceful wings, we
fly to the truth of the Church on wings of faith and reason.
Minnesota Catholicism

Are faith & wisdom two wings of a bird (somewhere) in Buddhism?




"Vijnanamaya is of the level of the intellect, the level of decision or determination. Again, Vijnanamaya kosa is thought of as a bird. The head of such bird is sraddha, faith and respect in the scriptures. Te right wing of the bird is rtam, righteousness and the left wing is satyam, truth. The body of the bird is said to be Yoga; yoga means complete absorption, complete identification. The tail of the bird, the support, is mahat which is Hiranyagarbha, the first manifestation of Brahman. "

https://files.cloudmini.net/download/MUFIv_v2.jpg

Wisdom and Compassion are the two wings or two wheels of a cart in Buddhism. This how the metaphor of two wings has been used in Buddhism. The concept behind this as that the Bodhi, the mind of awakening, is fusion of two different aspects of mind- wisdom and compassion. Yoga means to conjoin- yoga in this sense implies to join together these two states of mind. This in short is the context around the 2 wings.

M43 supports the bird analogy:

shrouded by ignorance and fettered by craving—taking pleasure
wherever they land


“How many conditions are there for the arising of right view?”
That is, for stream-entry.
“There are two conditions for the arising of right view: the voice
of another and rational application of mind. The “voice of another” is
the teachings of the Dhamma, but these have to be actually
investigated and applied internally. These are the two conditions for
the arising of right view.”
“When right view is supported by how many factors does it have
freedom of heart and freedom by wisdom as its fruit and benefit?” That is, how does a stream-enterer practice further for arahantship?
“When right view is supported by five factors it has freedom of heart
and freedom by wisdom as its fruit and benefit. It’s when right view
is supported by ethics, learning, discussion, serenity, and
discernment. When right view is supported by these five factors it has
freedom of heart and freedom by wisdom as its fruit and benefit.”

The right view is condition for freedom. The two conditions are faith in Dhamma (teaching), and wise application of the teaching. Developing confidence and wisdom is supported by ethics,learning, discussion, serenity, and discernment—free as a bird.

Very good answer. Impressive

This is directly quoted from what I wrote and I did in turn say I made a mistake as it is "faith and DOUBT are two wings of a bird" need to be balanced correctly in order to "fly" to gain wisdom.
Still from the question I quoted this in, about balancing/renewing faith, there is in fact the concept of the 5 spiritual faculties that do indeed need faith and wisdom to be equally balanced via mindfulness.
Bhikkhu Bodhi stated:

In the development of the faculties, faith and wisdom are to be balanced to avoid the extremes of blind credulity and intellectual cleverness; energy and concentration are to be balanced to avoid restless agitation and sluggish immobility of mind. But strong mindfulness is always necessary, for mindfulness oversees the development of the other faculties and ensures that they are kept in balance.

So one could use the same analogy to explain this concept.
Searching for sources of the analogy you will see both faith/doubt and wisdom/compassion uses of the analogy.
My original understanding of this analogy comes from a commentary to Gelug teachings on Lojong by Langri Tangpa.

I marked this answer down because i do not have the faintest idea of what Bhikkhu Bodhi attempted to impart.

How to correctly cultivate the 5 faculties, a part of the 37 factors of enlightenment. It is explained adequately in the link, as well in the wiki page of the subject https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indriya as too is his explanation from the Visuddhimagga and I assume abhidhamma.
